# List paging in Sencha

Tags: list, sencha-touch-2

I have created a list in Sencha touch2. I need to add paging to it. Lets say i need 25 items to be displayed in a page and on tap of "next" button, the next 25 items has to be displayed.
I believe sencha touch 2 provides paging but am not gettin a handle on it.

My code is

```
            cls:'inboxqueuecls',
            xtype:'list',
            id:'queuelist',
            store:'QueueStore',

            plugins: [{
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
                autoPaging: false,
                clearOnPageLoad: true

            }],
            style:{
                'border-right':'0.01px  black',
                'background-color':'rgba(0,140,153,0.2)'
            },
            itemTpl:'{queueName}'
```

and my store is

```
 pageSize: 20,
            autoload: false,
 proxy:{
            type:'memory',
            reader:{
                type:'xml',
                record:'string',
                rootProperty:'QueuesNames',


            }
        }
```

but the "page size" doesn seem to be working. 
Anything am missing? Please help.

Comment: try to put the autoLoad and the pageSize config on your store and not on the proxy's reader

Comment: Could you paste the structure of your JSON in your question.

Comment: I am gettin the data from the web services and storing it in this store.

Comment: Yes, I know. But could you add the structure of the data you're receiving

Comment: <b:string>Data Entry</b:string>
               <b:string>Data EntryError</b:string>
               <b:string>Except Proc</b:string>
               <b:string>Except ProcError</b:string>
               <b:string>Faxin</b:string>
               <b:string>FaxinError</b:string>
               <b:string>Faxout</b:string>
               <b:string>FaxoutError</b:string>
               <b:string>Invoice ProcError</b:string>
               <b:string>Invoice Processing</b:string>
               <b:string>Manager</b:string>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14388/discussion-between-khush-and-tdebailleul)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As TDEBailleul has said pageSize is an attribute of store not of the proxy.

Second, Memory proxy does not support paging. MemoryProxy has its own processing in the Store.js. Specify json or other proxy to get paged ajax call at the output. Another solution is MemoryProxy or ever from other ancestor subclassing.

Comment: i made it a json file and the page size is now in store. But there is still no difference in the output. Pagesize doesn seem to work at all.

Comment: I cannot help till you not share your code. On my app all is working